# open Big Data to solve cancer epidemiology challenge

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, big-data

I am a doctor and I am coordinator of a project that will call for innovative projects around challenges in the field of Big Data applied to Cancer Epidemiology. The specifity of the projects is to use open big datasets in order to serve them through an API for the callees of the project. So we're looking for these kind of sets

Are there sites that indicate open big health data sets links ? (knowing we're searching for heterogenous sources : clinical, behaviour, imagery...)

Comment: Have you looked at NIH SEERS incidence data sets?

Comment: @Skram yes I saw it but it is not Open, isn't it ?

Comment: SEER is not strictly open - you need to sign a data use agreement
http://seer.cancer.gov/data/

Comment: that is correct - requires a data user agreement

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in brain imaging data, you could check out the [Connectome Coordination Facility](https://www.humanconnectome.org/)

I downloaded the original HCP 1200 for our institution a couple of years free of charge. That's 7T & 3T imaging data for 1200 individuals. It's a large dataset but it is freely available for research.